# Need a working example for apache POI createDateConstraint not using formulas

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

the poi.apache.org website gives the following definition

public static DVConstraint createDateConstraint(int comparisonOperator,
                                java.lang.String expr1,
                                java.lang.String expr2,
                                java.lang.String dateFormat)

I want an example where expr1 and expr2 are formatted date values.

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me for setting cell style as date and adding date validation on it:

```
Cell cel= rowx.createCell(i);
cel.setCellStyle(style);
 XSSFCreationHelper createHelper = 
 workbook.getCreationHelper();
 short dateFormat = 
 createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
 style.setDataFormat(dateFormat);

 DataValidationHelper dvHelper = 
 sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
 DataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = 
      dvHelper.createDateConstraint(

 org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel. 
 DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType.BETWEEN, 
            "Date(1900, 1, 1)", 
            "Date(9999, 12, 31)", 
            "MM/dd/yyyy");
 CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(
            2, pendingRowCount, columnNumber, columnNumber);
 DataValidation validation = 
 dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
 if (validation instanceof XSSFDataValidation) {
   validation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
   validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
} else {
  validation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
}
sheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

Answer (score 1):

The key I found was using the Date(Year, Month, Day) function. I also needed my code to work for an entire column except for the header so the cell range is from 1 to the last row excel has for one sheet. I am unsure why but just a date on its own didn't seem to work because the formula is automatically converted to have a '=' sign in front which confuses excel I think.

Also an error style and message are always a good idea to give people an idea on what they are doing wrong.

```
DataValidationHelper dataValidationHelper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
DataValidationConstraint constraint = dataValidationHelper.createDateConstraint(OperatorType.BETWEEN,
            "Date(1990, 1, 1)", "Date(9999, 12, 31)", "mm/dd/yyyy");
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(1, 1048575, 0, 0);
DataValidation validation = dataValidationHelper.createValidation(constraint, addressList);
validation.setErrorStyle(DataValidation.ErrorStyle.STOP);
validation.createErrorBox("Invalid date", "Please Insert Valid Date");
validation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(dropDownArrow);
sheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the [cunningly named TestDataValidation junit test](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/testcases/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/TestDataValidation.java) that ships with Apache POI, which shows using `createDateConstraint`:

```
DataValidationHelper dataValidationHelper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
DataValidationConstraint constraint = dataValidationHelper.createDateConstraint(OperatorType.EQUAL,
            "2014/10/25", null, null);
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 0, 0, 0);
DataValidation validation = dataValidationHelper.createValidation(constraint, addressList);
sheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

That includes setting a date on the constraint, which shows the format needed

Comment: For me this didn't work. The excel file showed an equal sign in front of the date which seemed to confused it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the question is for JAVA, some C# developers like me coming to this page after searching in Google, hence, posting the C# version of the answer below.

```
private void AddDateTypeValidation(IWorkbook workbook, ISheet sheet, int[] regions)
    {
        int _startRow = 1, _endRow = Int16.MaxValue, // Start from first row & continue upto end of Excel.
            _startColumn = regions[0], _endColumn = regions[1]; // start column, end column

        XSSFDataValidation dataValidation;
        XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint;
        XSSFDataValidationHelper validationHelper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper((XSSFSheet)sheet);

        XSSFCellStyle dateCellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
        dateCellStyle.SetDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat("m/d/yy"));

        CellRangeAddressList _regions = new CellRangeAddressList(_startRow, _endRow, _startColumn, _endColumn);
        dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint)validationHelper.CreateDateConstraint(
                                                    OperatorType.BETWEEN, "Date(2000, 1, 1)", "Date(3000, 12, 31)", "m/d/yy");
        dataValidation = (XSSFDataValidation)validationHelper.CreateValidation(dvConstraint, _regions);

        dataValidation.ShowErrorBox = true;
        dataValidation.SuppressDropDownArrow = true;
        dataValidation.ErrorStyle = 0;
        dataValidation.CreateErrorBox("Invalid Input Provided", "Please enter a valid date in format 'm/d/yy'.");
        dataValidation.ShowErrorBox = true;
        dataValidation.CreatePromptBox("Date Validation", "Enter a Valid Date in format 'm/d/yy'.");
        dataValidation.ShowPromptBox = true;
        sheet.AddValidationData(dataValidation);
        sheet.SetDefaultColumnStyle(_startColumn, dateCellStyle);

        sheet.AddValidationData(dataValidation);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I need a BETWEEN constraint and I could not find any working solution. Finally I found out that it is relatively simple: you should provide expr1 (from) and expr2 (to) using the format defined in the fourth parameter dateFormat:

```
dataValidationHelper.createDateConstraint(OperatorType.BETWEEN,
  "1900-01-01", "2100-10-10", "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: The Date format provided is wrong, this is not working.